# What will be the answer of the expression $| t-2 |$?

Tags: real-numbers, absolute-value

What will be the answer of the expression $| t-2 |$?

Either $t + 2$  or $t - 2$ and How ?

Comment: What? This makes 0 sense, does it make sense to you?

Comment: The "answer" falls within a range of zero to positive infinity - 2

Comment: The function of modulo operator is to convert any negative to positive so in the above case what will be the answer?

Comment: We have no modulo operator here, but an absolut-value-operator.

Comment: Also, consider $-(t-2)=-t+2$, not $t+2$

Comment: It depends on $t$, which of the two are correct. For $t=2$, both $t-2$ and $-t+2$ give the correct result $0$

Comment: The above expression helps in determining the value of t in the expression | t - 2 | = 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $|x|=x$ is $x\geq 0$ and $|x|=-x$ if $x<0$.

Thus, $|t-2|=t-2$ is $t-2\geq0\iff t\geq 2$ and $|t-2|=-t+2$ if $t-2<0\iff t < 2$.

Answer (score 1):

If $t\ge 2$, we have $|t-2|=t-2$.

If $t<2$ , we have $|t-2|=-t+2=2-t$